# Why can't region and account ID be empty for SQS ARNs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm using `arn:aws:sqs:::queue_name` for my AWS IAM policy, but I receive access denied errors when trying to access the queue from Python's AWS wrapper, boto3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

S3 bucket names are unique across all accounts and regions, which means you don't need to specify the region or the account ID. For S3 buckets, you can use the following ARN without issues: `arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name`. This will apply the ARN to a single bucket with name equal to bucket_name.

However, SQS queue names are neither unique across accounts, nor across regions. That means you either need to specify the exact region or the account ID, or use the wildcard * character, which means the ARN applies to **all** queues with the same name. I used `arn:aws:sqs:*:*:queue_name` to apply the ARN to all queues with name equal to queue_name.